# jQuery Mobile how to set text to multiple input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

jQM code

```
for(var key in sessionStorage)
{
    var item = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    var viewItem = $.parseJSON(item);
    var titleR = viewItem.title;
    $(".showTitleR").val(titleR);
}
```

html code

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div>
         <input class="showTitleR" type="text" value="one and last value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can set only one and last value.
What I want is the list of all keys like this:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div>
         <input class="showTitleR" type="text" value="first" />
         <input class="showTitleR" type="text" value="..." />
         <input class="showTitleR" type="text" value="last" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Every input tag has to have titleR value which is text. And it has to be as much input tags as for loop iterations.

Comment: Do you have the same elements in sessionStorage as inputs you in your code?

Comment: Yes, I do, meaning every key value is a input value. Is that what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see and if I understand correctly what are you trying to do - you are changing value for the same HTML element. You either create new HTML element or clone current and then change its value.

```
var item = $(".showTitleR");
```

`item.clone().append(item.parent());`

Comment: If I use appaendto() and div tags, I have no problem with that. I cannot achieve that by using input tag.

Comment: As you said "And it has to be as much input tags as for loop iterations". So you have to create them. How do you want to create them just by setting only value for the same element in every loop?

Comment: Yes, you are right, every input tag has to be created and then text a value has to be added. It was not me who gave you minus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var key in sessionStorage){
    var item = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    var viewItem = $.parseJSON(item);
    var titleR = viewItem.title;
    $(".showTitleR:eq(0)").clone().val(titleR).insertAfter($(".showTitleR:last");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still as the result it is only one input tag even if I have 4 iteration and without text as the value.